# JavaScript Add rel="nofollow" on Returned Data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting data from a input text field, sending it to another file to process and showing the returned information using this function;

```
$(function() {
  $("#showitems").on("click",function() {
        var url = $("#url").val();
        if (url && $(this).is(":checked")) {

      $.post("details.php",
        { "url": url },
        function(data){
      $('.itemdetails').html(data);
        }
      ); 

    } else {

    }
  });
});
```

The returned data is an unordered list similar to this one:

```
<li><a href="http://www.google.com" title="Google" target="_blank">Google</li>
<li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" title="Yahoo" target="_blank">Yahoo</li>
<li><a href="http://www.bing.com" title="Bing" target="_blank">Bing</li>
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="Facebook" target="_blank">Facebook</li>
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" title="Twitter" target="_blank">Twitter</li>
```

Now, how can I append a 'rel="nofollow"' on each of the returned `<a href="">` tag ?

Sorry for the `rel="_blank"`, it should be `target="_blank"`. That was a mistake from my end.

The output will be on php page, and can easily be crawlable by search engines, that's why the nofollow will be nice.

Comment: What is the `rel="nofollow"` for? If it's for search engines' sake, this isn't going to make sense - a spider will never see what you add using JavaScript

Comment: What have you tried? Can't you just add this on the server side (in your `details.php` script)? `rel="_blank nofollow"`

Comment: With $(".itemdetails").find("a").attr("rel","nofollow") but why do you need this? As far as i know this is just an instruction for search engines.

Answer (score 4):

There is no point in adding `rel="nofollow"` using JavaScript. Search engines will not see it because they don't perform AJAX requests and generally don't execute JavaScript.

However, theoretically this should do the job anyway:

```
$('.itemdetails').html(data).find('a').attr('rel', 'nofollow');
```

But again, **search engines will not see this at all**.

By the way, `rel="_blank"` should most likely be `target="_blank"` if you want it to open in a new tab/window (which you shouldn't do by the way - it should be up to the user if he wants that or not).

Comment: And what if I store URLs in JS array and open this URLs by onclick event? How can I prevent such JS URLs from Google indexing?

Comment: If they are not plain old `<a href="some-url">` links they won't be indexed anyway.

Comment: And what about http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=mmoHmfy5AcQ#

Comment: Most likely that's about `#!/whatever` style links which are actually in the HTML code and not created using javascript.

Comment: It looks like Google do see JS links http://moz.com/ugc/new-reality-google-follows-links-in-javascript-4930